# How do I get similarity with autoencoders

Tags: deep-learning, similarity, autoencoder

I have build an autoencoder to extract from a very high dimensional (200 dimensions) space a smaller but significant representation (16 dimensions).

Now that I have these "encoded" vectors, I would like to compute some kind of similarity score, or clustering.

I am not sure which notion of distance to apply at this point. Any ideas how I can get similarity/clusters considering that I have used autoencoders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the **cosine similarity** between two encoded vectors you would like to compare. The cosine similarity between two vectors is defined as follows:

[image]